# What causes a fatal error when trying to filter items with children in Twig PHP file?

Tags: php, twig

I have this php file that filters items, but I cant see why the items with children give an error. Does anyone have any pointers to fix this? I get a fatal error with the filters for items that have children, or the children itself.

The error is `"urlencode(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given"`

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Rareloop\Lumberjack\Http\Responses\TimberResponse;
use Timber\PostQuery;
use Timber\Timber;

class ArchiveOfferController extends Controller
{
    public function handle()
    {
        global $wp_query;

        $templates = ['pages/archive-offer.twig', 'pages/archive.twig', 'pages/index.twig'];

        $context = Timber::context();

        $context['title'] = __('Vacancies', 'bvng');

        $context['filters'] = [
            ['key' => 'domain', 'name' => __('Domain/Discipline', 'bvng'), 'terms' => Timber::get_terms('domain', ['hide_empty' => true, 'parent' => 0])],
            ['key' => 'education_level', 'name' => __('Education level', 'bvng'), 'terms' => Timber::get_terms('education_level', ['hide_empty' => true])],
            ['key' => 'provinces', 'name' => __('Region', 'bvng'), 'terms' => Timber::get_terms('provinces', ['hide_empty' => true])],
            ['key' => 'hours', 'name' => __('Hours', 'bvng'), 'terms' => Timber::get_terms('hours', ['hide_empty' => true])],
        ];

        // Get the selected values for each parameter
        $selectedFilters = [];
        foreach ($context['filters'] as $filter) {
            $key = $filter['key'];
            $values = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : [];

            if (is_array($values)) {
                $values = array_filter($values, 'is_string');
                $selectedFilters[$key] = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $values);
            } elseif (is_string($values)) {
                $selectedFilters[$key] = [sanitize_text_field($values)];
            } else {
                $selectedFilters[$key] = [];
            }
        }

        // Update the selectedFilters array
        $context['selectedFilters'] = $selectedFilters;

        $queryArgs = $wp_query->query_vars;

        // Modify the query arguments based on the selected filters
        foreach ($selectedFilters as $key => $values) {
            if (!empty($values)) {
                $queryArgs[$key] = $values;
            }
        }

        $context['query_vars'] = $queryArgs;

        $context['posts'] = new PostQuery();

        // Build the new URL with properly encoded query string
        $newUrl = $this->buildUrlWithQueryString(get_post_type_archive_link('offer'), $queryArgs);

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $newUrl;

        return new TimberResponse($templates, $context);
    }

    private function buildUrlWithQueryString($baseUrl, $queryArgs)
    {
        $queryString = '';

        foreach ($queryArgs as $key => $values) {
            if (is_array($values)) {
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        foreach ($value as $subvalue) {
                            $queryString .= urlencode($key) . '[]=' . urlencode($subvalue) . '&';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $queryString .= urlencode($key) . '[]=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $queryString = rtrim($queryString, '&');
                return $baseUrl . '?' . $queryString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the twig file

```
 {% extends "layouts/base.twig" %}
 
 {% block content %}
     <div class="container mx-auto px-5 pb-5 lg:px-10 lg:pb-10">
         {% include 'molecules/navigations/breadcrumbs.twig' %}
         {% include 'molecules/global/page-header.twig' with {'title': title ~ ' (' ~ posts.found_posts ~ ')'} only %}
 
         <div class="mt-4 mx-auto lg:mt-6 lg:max-w-none">
             <form x-data action="{{ get_post_type_archive_link('offer') }}" method="GET">
                 <div class="grid grid-flow-row md:grid-flow-col flex-wrap space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-5 px-4 py-8 lg:p-8 bg-gray-500">
                     {% for f in filters %}
                         <div>
                             <label for="{{ f.key }}" class="block font-bold text-2xl">{{ f.name }}</label>
                             <select id="{{ f.key }}" name="{{ f.key }}[]" x-on:change="$el.form.submit()" class="dropdown" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
                                 <option value="">Select an option</option>
                                 <option value="" disabled>──────────</option>
                                 {% for term in f.terms %}
                                     {% set isSelected = term.slug in (query_vars[f.key] ?? []) %}
                                     <option value="{{ term.slug }}"{{ isSelected ? ' selected' : '' }}>
                                         {{ term.title }}
                                     </option>
                                     {% for child in term.children %}
                                         {% set isSelectedChild = child.slug in (query_vars[f.key] ?? []) %}
                                         <option value="{{ child.slug }}"{{ isSelectedChild ? ' selected' : '' }}>
                                             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ child.title|slice(term.title|length + 1) }}
                                         </option>
                                     {% endfor %}
                                 {% endfor %}
                             </select>
 
                         </div>
                     {% endfor %}
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
 
         <div class="mt-8 mx-auto lg:mt-12 lg:max-w-none lg:space-y-0">
             {% for post in posts %}
                 {# twigcs use-var post #}
                 {% include ['organisms/teases/tease-' ~ post.post_type ~ '.twig', 'organisms/teases/tease.twig'] %}
             {% else %}
                 <p>Geen vacature gevonden</p>
             {% endfor %}
         </div>
 
         {% include 'molecules/navigations/pagination.twig' with {pagination: posts.pagination} %}
     </div>
     <div class="container mx-auto px-5 lg:px-10">
         {% include 'molecules/global/open-application.twig' %}
     </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

I would like the filter to be a multiselect, and it works on items without children. Just dont understand why it doesnt work with children.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you are receiving? Please point that out in the question

Comment: Ah, apologies. I have updated my slack question

Comment: So the error happens in the PHP right?

Comment: correct. Fatal error when I select any of the filters with child elements. The other filters function correctly.

Comment: Unsure why this is tagged with `twig` then. Anyway instead of trying to build your own query string, have a look at [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)